# Why does nickel permeability decreases past 250 KHz?

Tags: magnetic-fields, metals

I found this graph of nickel magnetic permeability vs frequency,it start to drop at around 250 KHz.Why isnt the permeability constant at all frequencies?

Can that frequency curve somehow be predicted/calculated from other physical properties of nickel like for example DC permeability and conductivity?

[image]

Comment: Where is the plot from?  Do they explain the theory curve?